# Percorrer array de objetos react

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Pretendo dentro do meu componente pai criar uma função que irá percorrer todos os objetos armazenados no estado deste mesmo componente, verificando se o parâmetro indicado é igual ao valor `id` do objeto.

No meu componente filho pretendo usar essa função do componente pai indicando um valor como parâmetro e, no caso desse parâmetro se igualar ao valor `id`, retornar `true`.

Este valor booleano será usado dentro de um `if` neste componente filho.

A função que tentei criar no componente pai:

```
function validarId(novaId){
  Cadastros.map(cadastro => () => {
    if(cadastro.id == novaId){
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })
}
```

Tentativa de implementar a função dentro de uma condicional:

```
else if(validarId(id)){
  window.alert("Id já cadastrada!")
}
```

Aplicação completa:

Componente Pai:

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Table, Jumbotron} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Formulario from './Formulario'
import renderCadastros from './renderCadastros'

function App() {
  
  const [Cadastros, setCadastros] = useState([{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Francisca Julia da Costa",
    "cpf": "457.696.936-65",
    "rg": "47.360.897-2",
    "data_nasc": "23/03/1944",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Noah Felipe Silva",
    "cpf": "956.531.431-70",
    "rg": "40.974.782-8",
    "data_nasc": "11/07/1964",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Alícia Rosângela Melo",
    "cpf": "066.291.353-18",
    "rg": "36.214.141-1",
    "data_nasc": "18/02/1978",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  }]) 
  
  function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro){
    setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
      return cadastrosAtuais.concat(novoCadastro)
    })
  }

  function validarId(novaId){
    Cadastros.map(cadastro => () => {
      if(cadastro.id == novaId){
        return true
      }
      else {
        return false
      }
    })
  }

  return (
  <Jumbotron style={{background: 'transparent'}}> 
    <Formulario validarId={validarId} atualizarCadastros={atualizarCadastros} />
    <Table striped bordered hover size='sm'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>CPF</th>
          <th>RG</th>
          <th>Nascimento</th>
          <th>Sexo</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {Cadastros.map(renderCadastros)}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  </Jumbotron>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Componente filho:

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {Button, Form, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'

function Formulario ({atualizarCadastros, validarId}){
  const refId = useRef()
  const refNome = useRef()
  const refCpf = useRef()
  const refRg = useRef()
  const refNascimento = useRef()
  const refSexo = useRef()

  function registrarCadastros(){
    const id = refId.current.value
    const nome = refNome.current.value
    const cpf = refCpf.current.value
    const rg = refRg.current.value
    const nascimento = refNascimento.current.value
    const sexo = refSexo.current.value

    const novoCadastro = {'id': id, 'nome': nome, 'cpf': cpf, 'rg': rg, 'data_nasc': nascimento, 'sexo': sexo}

    if(id == '' || nome == '' || cpf == '' || rg == '' || nascimento == '' || sexo == '' ){
      window.alert("Existem campos em branco!")
    }

    else if(validarId(id)){
      window.alert("Id já cadastrada!")
    }

    else{
    atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro)

    refId.current.value = null
    refNome.current.value = null
    refCpf.current.value = null
    refRg.current.value = null
    refNascimento.current.value = null
    refSexo.current.value = null
    }
  }

  return(
    <div>
    <Form>
    <Form.Row>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Identificação</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refId} placeholder="Id" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Nome Completo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refNome} placeholder="João Silva" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>CPF</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refCpf} placeholder="000.000.000-00" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>RG</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refRg} placeholder="0.000.000" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Data de Nascimento</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refNascimento} placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Sexo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refSexo} placeholder="Masculino/Feminino" />
      </Col>
    </Form.Row>
    </Form>
    <div  style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Button onClick={registrarCadastros} style={{margin: '10px'}} variant="primary">Cadastrar</Button>
    </div> 
  </div>
  )  
}

export default Formulario
```

Outro componente da aplicação:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

function renderCadastros(cadastro, index){
    return(
    <tr id={cadastro.id} key={index}>
        <td>{cadastro.id}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.nome}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.cpf}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.rg}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.data_nasc}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.sexo}</td>
        <td align="center"><Button variant="danger">Excluir</Button></td>
    </tr>)
  }

  export default renderCadastros
```

Comment: se poderia explicar melhor? não tem um exemplo minimo razoável para dar uma resposta

Comment: Editei o post com a aplicação inteira, obrigado!

Comment: Quero que seja possível bloquear o cadastro com uma Id que já existe

Comment: eu não consigo entender o que você deseja realmente fazer?

Comment: A função registrarCadastros() cria uma linha na tabela com os valores inseridos no formulário. então esses valores são inseridos no useState do componente pai e então a aplicação é renderizada novamente. Dentro dessa função também existem alguns ifs que representam as restrições que quero incluir pra adicionar esta linha. Um que já está feito é o de não deixar cadastros em branco serem adicionados. E  o outro que quero é que não seja permitido adicionar cadastros com id que já existem no Usestate do componente pai

Comment: Então minha dúvida seria sobre como verificar esses ids que já existem no Usestate do pai e comparar com o id que está sendo inserido no formulário

Comment: se tem que usar filter

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro

Comment: A maior dificuldade no caso é conseguir fazer esta função e usar no componente filho, como visto lá em cima no código. Ou seja, criar esta função de loop no "pai" e passar ela como prop para o "filho", e dentro do filho usar esta função com o parâmetro que desejo verificar. Alguma dica? @novic

Comment: A função `validarId` está retornando um array de funções, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Não, o objetivo era que essa função fizesse o mapeamento dos Cadastros no State do componente, verificando se o valor "id" é o mesmo que o id inserido como parâmetro. Ela não está funcionando. @Luiz Felipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beleza, Diego?

Olha, um ponto que eu consegui perceber que pode estar tendo inconsistência do que é esperado, é na sua função `validarId`.

A função `map` serve para transformar um array em outro, utilizando uma função passada. No seu caso, a função monta um array que deve ficar algo como: `[true, false, false]` (imaginando que o id passado já existe na primeira posição), mas  ela está sempre retornando `null`, já que não existe valor de retorno nela, e por isso a validação não está ocorrendo de forma correta.

Você pode usar a função `some`, que retorna `true` ou `false` se um a função passada tiver qualquer retorno `true`, e retornar esse resultado. Ficaria algo assim:

```
function validarId(novaId){
  return Cadastros.some(cadastro => () => {
    if(cadastro.id == novaId){
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })
}
```

A função vai rodar o array `Cadastros` e, se o valor da `novaId` for igual ao de qualquer `id` já cadastrado, ele retorna `true` na função, o que faria ele dar o alerta e não entrar no `else` dos cadastros (no seu formulário). Ela pode ser escrita de forma simplificada também:

```
function validarId(novaId){
  return Cadastros.some(cadastro => cadastro.id == novaId)
}
```

Se puder dar uma outra recomendação, deixe mais claro o que essa função faz. `validarId` é bem ok no início, mas pode ficar muito vago sobre qual vai ser o retorno dela, o que pode causar confusão lá na parte de validação em si (espera-se que a `validarId` retorne `true` quando o `id` é válido ou quando ele já existe?). Tente usar nomes mais claros e que tenham uma resposta lógica de retorno, algo como `idExiste` ou algo nessa linha, que já te dê uma resposta se você usar o nome da função como 'pergunta'.

Comment: Primeiramente Thiago parabéns pela resposta, muito bem explicativa! Muito obrigado, hoje a noite irei implementar ela, aí aceito sua resposta!!